# 'System.Windows.Data.MultiBinding' is not a valid value for property 'Text'

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, multibinding, markup-extensions

I'm trying to write a custom `MarkupExtension` that allows me to use my own mechanisms for defining a binding, however when I attempt to return a `MultiBinding` from my `MarkupExtension` I get the above exception.

I have:

```
<TextBlock Text="{my:CustomMarkup ...}" />
```

`CustomMarkup` returns a `MultiBinding`, but apparently `Text` doesn't like being set to a `MultiBinding`. How come it works when I say:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding ... />
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

But it doesn't work the way I'm doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't return the `MultiBinding` itself. Instead, return the result of `MultiBinding.ProvideValue`.

BTW, what exactly are you doing in your markup extension ? Perhaps you could just inherit from `MultiBinding`, if you don't need to override `ProvideValue` (which is sealed). You can achieve almost anything by just setting the appropriate `Converter` and other properties

Comment: Just what I was going to write, but you beat me to it.

Comment: Interesting. My custom extension essentially gives me a way to define bindings as results of a method in my code-behind, and gets the dependencies for the binding from custom attributes I attach to the method. It's pretty cool if I don't say so myself. :)

I'm thinking of publishing it if it ends up working out well.

Answer (score 0):

Did some investigating, and it turns out I'm supposed to actually set the binding in the MarkupExtension's ProvideValue method and then return the current value of the binding. A little counter-intuitive but so far seems to be working!

Here's roughly what I ended up with:

```
public override object ProvideValue( IServiceProvider serviceProvider ) {
    IProvideValueTarget valueProvider = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService( typeof( IProvideValueTarget ) );
    // only need to do this if they're needed in your logic:
    object @target = valueProvider.TargetObject;
    object @property = valueProvider.TargetProperty;

    MultiBinding result = new MultiBinding();

    // set up binding as per custom logic...

    return result.ProvideValue( serviceProvider );
}
```

Add a little logic, dust lightly with error handling and serve.

**Update:** Turns out MultiBinding.ProvideValue() hooks up the binding itself, based on the target and property information in `serviceProvider`. That's much cleaner.

Comment: I think MultiBinding.ProvideValue already performs the BindingOperations.SetBinding... so you're doing it twice

Comment: P.S. I just use the '@' symbols to make the variables look special... serves no functional purpose.

Comment: Wait, how could it? It doesn't know what the binding is until I set it.

Comment: Oh I see, it gets them from serviceProvider... interesting.

Comment: You're doing too much.  To get the binding set, you only need to return a BindingExpressionBase (NOT a BindingBase) from your ProvideValue.

Comment: You're right, it works, cool. That's a bit cleaner at least. I will update the answer.